# how to set default value from axios call to selectfield in a form

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I am trying to set a default value on a select field from a database value using axios.  That way during a page load/refresh the value is from the database and not a blank value.  I am able to get the correct value from the method but can't assign it to the html select field that is in a `v-for`.

```html
<template>
  <div v-for="(item, index) in shopping_cart_items_list">
    <select
      @change="itemamount($event, item)"
        v-model="selected[currentitemamount(item, index)]"
        :key="item.id"
    >
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
      <option value="7">7</option>
      <option value="8">8</option>
      <option value="9">9</option>
      <option value="10">10</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  data() {
    return { selected: "" };
  },
  methods: {
    currentitemamount(item, index) {
      axios({
        method: "get",
        url: "/checkout/currentquantity/" + item.id,
        headers: authHeader(),
      }).then((response) => {
        this.selected = response.data.amount;
        console.log(this.selected)
      });
    },
},
</script>
```

Comment: have the select v-model watch the reactive data, not call the async function... `v-model="selected"`

Comment: could you give an example im a backend developer :/

Comment: Simply replace the v-model as I suggest in the comment. That's the whole answer.  What the markup is doing now is calling an async function that doesn't return anything.

Comment: I'm trying to understand `selected[currentitemamount(item, index)]` AND `this.selected = response.data.amount`  one is expecting an array, but the data sets `selected: "" `, and it's not clear what the data type of `response.data.amount` is. Can you clarify?

Comment: response.data.amount returns an integer 1-10.  A person ads an item to a shopping cart and the quantity is between 1 and 10.  Its like amazon.com/checkout where you select a quantity 1-10.

Comment: The problem is when a person refreshes the page or comes back to there shopping cart, the selectfield value is blank rather than the integer value from there database shopping cart value.

Comment: @Anekdotin I added an answer. Hope that will work as per your expectation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending much time trying to use different answers it was actually pretty simple.  In the loop assign v-model="item.current_amount".  No method was needed.

```
<template>
  <div v-for="(item, index) in shopping_cart_items_list">
    <select
      @change="itemamount($event, item)"
        v-model="item.current_amount"
        :key="item.id"
    >
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
      <option value="7">7</option>
      <option value="8">8</option>
      <option value="9">9</option>
      <option value="10">10</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  data() {},
  methods: {
    
    },
},
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

As `currentitemamount(item, index)` returns an integer between `1-10`, Then you can simply use **:**

`currentitemamount(item, index)` instead of `selected[currentitemamount(item, index)]` in v-model and you can return `response.data.amount` instead of assigning it to `this.selected`.

**Demo :**

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  data:{
    shopping_cart_items_list: ['item1']
  },
  methods: {
    currentitemamount(item, index) {
      // axios call
            return 2; // response.data.amount
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(item, index) in shopping_cart_items_list" :key="index">
    <select @change="itemamount($event, item)"
        v-model="currentitemamount(item, index)">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
      <option value="7">7</option>
      <option value="8">8</option>
      <option value="9">9</option>
      <option value="10">10</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% clear about how `shopping_cart_items_list` is initialized, but say you have an array of objects, and an async method that provides an initial value for each object.

1. Markup as you have it (now, after the edit)
2. `data` needs an array of N values, since the markup produces N selects.  (note that data should be initialized to a function)

```
    data: function () {  
      return {
        selected: [],
        shopping_cart_items_list: [] // presumed
      };
    },
```

3. To have this work on a page load, use the `mounted` hook. Init the shopping cart (however you've been able to do it), then get the select values concurrently...

```
    data: function() { /*see above*/ },
    async mounted() {
      this.shopping_cart_items_list = await this.whateverIDoToInitCartItems();
      const promises = this.shopping_cart_items_list.map((item, index) => {
        return currentitemamount(item, index);
      });
      // the punchline: get all of the (plural) amounts and assign to the array
      this.selected = await Promise.all(promises);
    },
    methods: { /* ... */ },
```